# Brazil Sitecore User Group: our very first meeting!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

Date/Time (EST): Thursday, November 17, 2016, 4:00 - 7:00 PM

Date/Time (UTC): Thursday, November 17, 2016, 9:00 - 12:00 PM

Location: Vilaj Coworking, Rua Lauro Linhares, número 1281, sala 4, Florianópolis

RSVP: https://www.meetup.com/SUG-BR/events/235015472/

Please join us for the first Sitecore Brasil User Group meeting!

Our first meeting in Florianópolis we will discuss our impressions from the MVP Summit & Sitecore Symposium, roled out last September in New Orleans, EUA. We will also talk about getting started with Coveo for Sitecore. Last but not least, will discuss Mobile Apps development with Sitecore Mobile SDK, having SItecore as content management system.

Agenda:

7:00 - 7:30 - Networking e refreshments

• 7:00 - 8:00 - MVP Summit & Sitecore Symposium Recap - Rodrigo Peplau

• 8:00 - 8:10 - Q&A

• 8:10 - 8:40 - Getting started with  Coveo for Sitecore - Diego Moretto

• 8:40 - 8:50 - Q&A

• 8:50 - 9:20 - Mobile Apps with Sitecore Mobile SDK - João Amancio Neto

• 9:20 - 9:30 - Q&A

• 9:30 - 10:00 - Networking

PS: All sessions with be in portuguese and will be broadcasted

Comment: Please include UTC times

Comment: I've edited the original post. Done

Comment: Thank you Diego for sharing